# Prevent document from closing in DockingManager

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock, xceed

Here's a sample, which uses `DockingManager` (a.k.a [AvalonDock](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock&referringTitle=Home)) from Extended WPF Toolkit.

View model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool CanClose { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
    <Grid>
        <xcad:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding}">
            <xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Here's person name:"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcad:DockingManager.Resources>

            <xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>

            <xcad:LayoutRoot>
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane />
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot>
        </xcad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new[]
        {
            new Person { Name = "John" },
            new Person { Name = "Mary", CanClose = true },
            new Person { Name = "Peter", CanClose = true },
            new Person { Name = "Sarah", CanClose = true },
        };
    }
}
```

I want to prevent documents from closing via `CanClose` property in my view model. 
I've expected, that there must be some style for documents container, so, I'll write something like:

```
<Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Content.CanClose}"/>
```

and everything will work. But looks like there's no such style in `DockingManager`.

Am I missing something?

**Update**.

Of course, I can write an attached behavior, which will listen to `DockingManager.DocumentClosing` event and dispatch it to any view model, which will be bound to `DockingManager`. But it seems to me very stupid...

Another way is to handle event in the view:

```
private void DockingManager_DocumentClosing(object sender, Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DocumentClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !((Person)e.Document.Content).CanClose;
}
```

But it is definitely not a MVVM-way, and I like data binding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ContentViewModel - you can have an ICommand Close {get;set;} property and bind it to the LayoutItem's close command.

You can use a DelegateCommand for this on your ContentViewModel which can be used to determine if you can close the document or not (setting e.Cancel = true should stop the close command).